# Symfony Form Validation EntityType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

For a contact form i have two entities.

```
class ContactRequest
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    [...]

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ContactCategory")
     * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="integer")
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="message", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $message;


    [...]


}
```

And

```
class ContactCategory
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    [...]


    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Then my form

```
class ContactRequestType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('requesterFirstname', Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Prénom'))
            ->add('requesterLastname', Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom'))
            ->add('requesterMail', Type\EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email'))
            ->add('requesterPhone', Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Téléphone'))
            ->add('message', Type\TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Message'))
            $builder->add('type', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'CargoApiBundle:ContactCategory',
                'group_by' => 'group',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ( $options ) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('cc')
                        ->where('cc.site = :site')->setParameter('site', $options['site'])
                        ->orderBy('cc.group', 'ASC')
                        ->orderBy('cc.name', 'ASC');
                }
            ]);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'short' => false,
            'site' => null,
            'data_class' => 'Cargo\ApiBundle\Entity\ContactRequest'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The display works just fine but when i submit my form, it throws en error on the type field " This value should be of type integer ". Seems logical as it must be the id of my contact category.

So i looked at the form generated code and found nothing wrong :

```
<select id="contact_request_type" name="contact_request[type]" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Général">
        <option value="4">Autre</option>
        <option value="3">Du partenariat/sponsoring</option>
        <option value="1">Le fonctionnement de l'association</option>
        <option value="2">Un tournoi internationnal</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Une section">[...]</optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Le site">[...]</optgroup>
</select>
```

So i dumped the request content to see what was submitted and got this :

```
array (size=3)
  'action' => string 'contact_send' (length=12)
  'contact_request' => 
    array (size=7)
      'requesterFirstname' => string 'Kiro' (length=5)
      'requesterLastname' => string 'Staz' (length=4)
      'requesterMail' => string 'me@me.com' (length=18)
      'requesterPhone' => string '0000000000' (length=10)
      'type' => string '2' (length=1)
      'message' => string 'test' (length=17)
      '_token' => string '32LuZWWh8h-6lMlEShrjrs1w5HspaX0R4WikcGf5u3o' (length=43)
```

My datas are rigth but the contact_request['type'] is dumped as a string and i think that the issue, it should be an integer type are validated as an integer.

Can someone give me a clue on what i am doing wrong ?

I have no custom constraint validators.

Thank you !

Comment: What's your Symfony and PHP version?

Comment: Symfony 3.3.2 and PHP 7.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any `@Column` annotation for association field. Doctrine will figure it out what type of column it should be basing on `ContactCategory` primary key's type.

Remove

```
 * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="integer")
```

from `ContactRequest::$type`

Comment: Erf... it use to be a property of my entity and i forgot to remove the annotation when i associate the category.

After changing it, recreating the database and clearing the cache, i still have the error